# Stock Analysis Equation Questions

Tags: investing, accounting, stock-valuation, yahoo-finance, value-investing

I am a newer value investor and I am trying to slowly learn. I came across these equations and I am not able to find for sure online or in the books I have available what these abbreviations/acronyms might mean. Any help would be so greatly appreciated:

Gross Inc / TQ

cfEBIT adj / TQ

Net Acos / sh

Any idea what the "TQ", "cfEBIT adj" and "Acos" might stand for?

Also the acronym "CROSIC" as well.

Thank you very much,
Josh

Comment: where did you see these equations?

Comment: Quibble: Those are formulas, or expressions, not equations; they don't say what the result is supposed to be equal to.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing where you are seeing this I'm guessing at some of these.

My guess is that "TQ" = "trailing quarter"

The only "ACO" reference I'm aware of is related to healthcare companies...Accountable Care Organization

CfEbit=cash flow earning before interests and taxes.  So they're looking at that amount per share.

Comment: Good catch on TQ - I was guessing ACOS = Actual (or Average) Cost of Sales but those are pure guesses.